# Server not servering random files

Tags: apache, ubuntu, upgrade

I currently run on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. I'm not a server admin by any means, and just really have basic setup/config knowledge. I got a virtual box so I could learn more. Unfortunately, I just took a bit of a leap and screwed everything up.

I'm running Apache2, PHP, MySQL. This morning, I got a prompt saying I could update my server. I wasn't thinking and decided to go through with it. In addition to completely screwing up my server settings, I'm pretty sure I've lost data. But first I need to get my server running properly again (and probably never update without paying someone to do it for me).

I got most things up and running, but now when I go to my site (gamersplane.com), some paths end up 404'ing, and going to the Apache 404 instead of hitting the htaccess. The way I have it setup, the htaccess should get all files (barring things like css, js, images, xml, etc), and direct it all to a file called dispatch.php which processes the url and determines what to do/load. Basically, some stuff goes to the htaccess, other stuff isn't. I'm not sure why.

Mainly, files directly under /javascript won't load, but files in subfolders of /javascript do. In addition, going to /tools (folder exists) works, but /tools/cards (folder doesn't exist) doesn't. Strangely though, /forum (folder exists) and /forum/3 (doesn't exist) both work. I can't figure out when things do or don't work (systematically).

```
apache.conf: http://pastebin.com/A3J4bXE3

gamersplane.conf: http://pastebin.com/TAD06h59
```

### Update

I found out about package called javascript-common which forces /javascript to search elsewhere. I uninstalled the package, and JavaScript is now loading. I'm told I need the package, but I don't know why.

This still doesn't solve why some other paths don't work.

Comment: please append the contents of your active apache config file(s) usually to be found in /var/apache2/sites-enabled/

Comment: I attached pastebins of both the apache.conf and the site conf.

Comment: This sounds like a difficult problem, but it sounds like the sort of thing that one would need to have server access in order to figure out. I wonder if it is worth deleting then, on the basis it has not attracted any answers in three years?